# How to make HTML element overlap dynamically using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, overlap

I'm trying to style my image gallery so the next and previous buttons will be on the side and the expanded button will be in the corner and stay in their position dynamically and this is what I got so far[image]

This is my code structure

```
<div className="container">
  <i className="fa-solid fa-expand" />
  <div className="left-arrow" onClick={goPrevious}>❰</div>
  <img className="gallery-images" src={${photos[currentIndex].url}} alt="" />
  <div className="right-arrow" onClick={goNext}>❱</div>
  <div className="dot-container"> {photos.map((photo, index) => ( <div className="dot" key={index} onClick={()=> goToPhoto(index)}> ● </div> ))}     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this my code structer
   <div className="container">
      <i className="fa-solid fa-expand" />
      <div className="left-arrow" onClick={goPrevious}>❰</div>

      <img className="gallery-images" src={`${photos[currentIndex].url}`} alt="" />

      <div className="right-arrow" onClick={goNext}>❱</div>

      <div className="dot-container">
        {photos.map((photo, index) => (
          <div className="dot" key={index} onClick={() => goToPhoto(index)}>
            ●
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

These articles on MDN will help you get started with the needed CSS:

I would suggest to position the expand button relative to its parent container, more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

If you make the parent container a flexbox the arrows should be positioned left and right of the image, more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Please also provide a CSS code snipped if you need further assistance.